# How to reduce this polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(I\sqrt{3})$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $P(x) = x^4+x^3+3x^2+2x+2$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. How can I reduce this polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})[x]$??

I've proved that this polynomial doesn't have rational roots. But I can't find some root nor reduce this polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. Can you help me??

Comment: P factors into (x^2+2)(x^2+x+1), next step is to find how the second factor splits in Q(isqrt(3))

Comment: Ok, now I can solve that, but how did you find this factors? I've tried this way:    $p(x)= (x^2+bx+c)(x^2+dx+e)$, but is hard to solve the system

Comment: @Joãonani  the nontrivial cube roots of $1$ satisfy $x^3 - 1 = 0$  and thus $x^2 + x + 1.$   They are $$ \frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt 3}{2} $$ and can be constructed as soon as you have $i \sqrt 3$  available. That is, the particular complex number suggested the likely factor $x^2 + x + 1$

Comment: @Joãonani rewrite 3x^2 as x^2+2x^2 and the rest should be clear